Sync Jfrog with IntellJ and Maven
Good morning,
I would like some help resolving a problem with maven and JFROG Artifactory
I'm using Jfrog Artifactory to store my .jar artifacts generated by various libraries.
When the Lib is under development, we are generating new versions of the .jar with the same name: artists-SNAPSHOT.jar
So I upload the new .jar to JFROG, always with the same name.
When you use a LIB in my IDE (IntelJ) or maven, you cannot download the new version that is on the Jfrog Server.
can anybody help me?
I tried the IntellJ IDE settings to always enable the option to search on the server.
I used reloading the libs directly in the terminal.

Am I got you right that you don't change dependency version after changing code in it? Will it be resolved by Maven from command line?
